# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server class compatibility among different SQL Server versions

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

Here is my question: I have a server running SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) and I'm trying to create a PowerShell script to perform some administrative tasks.

This PowerShell script uses a method called `EnumServerPermissions` on the class `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo`. According to the [official MS documentation on this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.enumserverpermissions.aspx) this is only supported on SQL Server 2012 onwards.

Now my question is this: since this class lives inside `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll`, isn't there a way to run an updated version of the SQL Server Management Objetcs (SMO) that is compatible with this method call, even on an older version of SQL Server (such as my 2008 R2)? Do I have to accept this just doesn't run on my version? Or is there a way to make it work by updating something?

Thanks!

Comment: I am unsure on the specifics of this particular class, but in general when a feature like this isn't supported on a particular version it is because the interface/setting that the method would interact with or change isn't available even if you had the updated class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that Microsoft documentation is stating it only supports SQL Server 2012 + because of this:
[image]

That would be incorrect, and not officially stating what version it supports and doesn't support. SMO is treated just like SQL Server Management Studio. You can utilize a new version to connect to any version of SQL Server. The only stipulation is certain properties or classes would fail based on the property not existing on lower versions of SQL Server or feature is not available (e.g. AvailabilityGroup namespace on SQL Server 2008 R2 would fail).

As an example, in the PowerShell module [dbatools](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools) we have the latest version of SMO packaged with that module. So if you installed that module on a brand new machine you could connect to any version of SQL Server, from 2000+. We have commands in that module that support running against SQL Server 2000 and then some that only for 2012+ version of SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you @ShawnMelton for your response!

The reason I came across this seeming incompatibility between EnumServerPermissions and my server was because I was running some Puppet code (that in turn, executed some PowerShell code) that was failing. At some point in time I was gettting this error
`Powershell dsc resource MSFT_xSQLServerPermission failed to execute Test-TargetResource Cannot find an overload for EnumServerPermissions and the argument count 2`. Today though, I tried to reproduce this error (on the same server) by...

Comment: ... creating a 15 line PowerShell script using EnumServerPermissions with 2 parameters and to my surprise it just worked. So I went back to the original Puppet code and voila! working again!... for the love of God I can't explain why it was failing a few days ago and it is now working (I hate when this happens), but I'm assuming that something in my target box related to Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo got updated and because of that it is now working. Two final things I'm left wondering: 1. If the combo box in the document is to indicate compatibility, what is it for?...

Comment: What is the fact that there are only 2012 and 2014 showing up telling us in that page? 2. How do I check my version of Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo? Should I look into the properties of the Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll or is there a better way to check that?

Comment: In reference to the 2012 and 2014 being only versions, it is just how they have done MSDN docs. Microsoft is actually upgrading to [a new format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/smo-object-model-namespaces) but you can see even the links for SMO still point to the MSDN pages. A lot of the SMO and .NET docs are still sitting over on MSDN site, with no real timeline as to when it will be moved.

Comment: On checking what version of SMO, there are a few custom functions written but no magical cmdlet or built-in function to call to check it. We have a command in dbatools that you are more than welcome to borrow the code to validate in your scripts: [dbatools/Test-DbaSqlManagementObject](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/master/functions/Test-DbaSqlManagementObject.ps1)

Comment: @MartinSurasky I'd note that working with DSC is a different beast altogether. The worker functions in `xSqlServer` resource work out loading SMO for you if I recall. Which SMO would have to be present on the target nodes for that to work properly.